# ROBOFLOW-tensorflow-object-detection-faster-rcnn_ cannot import name 'get_config' from 'tensorflow.python.eager.context'

Tags: faster-rcnn, tensorflow-model-garden

I was trying to implement Fast RCNN model on my custom dataset using the google colab ROBOFLOW-tensorflow-object-detection-faster-rcnn.ipynb, but when I run the 'Install required packages' section ,Iam getting the error 'cannot import name 'get_config' from 'tensorflow.python.eager.context' . I tried to upgrade tensorflow and Keras , but not working

Tried Upgrade of tensorflow
Also trying to locally download the repository to try to import from tensorflow. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade the tensorflow:

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

For me TF2.9 worked for the same ROBOFLOW colab notebook:

```
!yes|pip uninstall tensorflow
!pip install tensorflow==2.9
```

Comment: can anyone run the google colab ROBOFLOW-tensorflow-object-detection-faster-rcnn.ipynb?